# How to combine multiple columns to single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table named Table1 which looks like the below one

```
| Name | X | Y | Z |
|------|---|---|---|
|    A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|    B | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|    C | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

I need to convert the above table into below one.

```
| NAME | VALUE |
|------|-------|
|   AX |     1 |
|   AY |     2 |
|   AZ |     3 |
|   BX |     4 |
|   BY |     5 |
|   BZ |     6 |
|   CX |     7 |
|   CY |     8 |
|   CZ |     9 |
```

Please help me how to do it. I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Do you know how many columns you have?  Are they really determined by the last character of `Name`?

Comment: That's kinda confusing. So your column names are Name, X, Y, and Z. and example records are: A, 1, 2, 3..... B, 4, 5, 6.. etc?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT Name + Col AS Name,
       Value
FROM   YourTable UNPIVOT (Value FOR Col IN ([X], [Y], [Z])) U
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e5c9/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does 'U' in the end specify?

Comment: @user2691260 - It's a required table alias for the `UNPIVOT` part. You can do `SELECT U.*
FROM   YourTable UNPIVOT (Value FOR Col IN ([X], [Y], [Z])) U` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cross apply` and `values`

```
select T1.Name+T2.Name as Name,
       T2.Value
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply(values(T1.X, 'X'),
                    (T1.Y, 'Y'),
                    (T1.Z, 'Z')) as T2(Value, Name)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af045/1)

Comment: @user2691260 please accept the answer that works best for you so that when others come to this question with the same problem they see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns is different or even unknown it would be a little bit more complicated, but knowing the columns this would work -

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Name, Value)
SELECT [Name] + 'X', [X]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name] + 'Y', [Y]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name] + 'Z', [Z]
FROM Table1
```

The answer above is a better solution anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to directly add comments to your answers (or questions, for that matter). If you have more to add, **edit** your post. You should only need to comment on your own posts if you're responding to someone else's comments.

Comment: Fair enough, should have probably added above.